# Assign value of text input to variable

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

When I run the program it sends `"great things happened"` to the azure table.

What I want to do is create a text box on the user interface that will let the users enter the value to be sent to the azure table.

I created a submit button but do not know how to link the button to the textbox.

How do i submit the info to get it to my azure database?

```
var item = { text: "Great things happened!" };
client.getTable("Item").insert(item);
```

This is what I have tried

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById('user-input');
var item = { text: inputBox}; client.getTable("Item").insert(item);
```

With HTML

```
<input id="user-input">
```

Comment: This is what I had before

     var item = { text: "Great things happened" };
        client.getTable("Item").insert(item);


This is what I have now:

 var inputBox = document.getElementById('user-input')
       
        var item = { text: inputBox};
        client.getTable("Item").insert(item);

and i have  <input id="user-input"> in my html.  How do i submit the info to get it to my azure database?  

I created  a submit button but do not know how to link the button to the textbox.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Put an input box on your html page, something like:

`<input id="user-input">`

Then get access to it by doing:

`var inputBox = document.getElementById('user-input')`

Now you can lookup the value in the textbox using: `inputBox.value`